# Error in m-m consult on sequelize on many-to-many relationship

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

i'm developing a API using Express with Sequelize acessing  a DB in MariaDB.

Occurs that in route on i have a relation m-m i can not do a index method bring all data.

This is my method to get data

```
import BClientName from '../models/BClientName';
import GAddress from '../models/GAddress';
import GPhone from '../models/GPhone';
import BClientRegister from '../models/BClientRegister';

async indexClientsName(req, res) {
    try {
      const clients = await BClientName.findAll({
        attributes: ['id', 'name'],
        include: [{
          model: BClientRegister,
          as: 'BClientRegisters',
          attributes: ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'client_id', 'address_id'],
          include: [{
            model: GAddress,
            as: 'GAddresses',
            attributes: ['id', 'street', 'number', 'neighborhood', 'zip', 'city', 'state', 'country'],
          }, {
            model: GPhone,
            as: 'GPhones',
            attributes: ['id', 'ddd', 'number', 'type'],
          }],
        }],
      });
```

This is the method to store data:

```
async storePhone(req, res) {
    try {
      const { id } = req.params;
      const { address_id, phones_id } = req.body;

      if (!id) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: ['Faltando ID Usuário'],
        });
      }

      if (!address_id) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: ['Faltando ID Endereço'],
        });
      }

      if (!phones_id) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: ['Faltando ID Fone'],
        });
      }
      const client_id = id;
      const client = await BClientName.findByPk(id);
      const phone = await GPhone.findByPk(phones_id);
      const address = await GAddress.findByPk(address_id);

      if (!client) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: ['Cliente não cadastrado'],
        });
      }

      if (!phone) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: ['Telefone não cadastrado'],
        });
      }

      if (!address) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: ['Endereço não cadastrado'],
        });
      }

      const newClient = await BClientRegister.create({ client_id, phones_id, address_id });
      return res.json(newClient);
    } catch (e) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while fetching data.' });
    }
```

This is the model BClientName

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

export default class BClientName extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        name: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          defaultValue: '',
          validate: {
            notEmpty: {
              msg: 'Campo não pode ser vazio.',
            },
          },
        },
        nick_name: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        obs: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
      },
      {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'b_clients_name',
      },
    );
    return this;
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsToMany(models.GAddress, { through: 'b_clients_register', foreignKey: 'client_id' });
    this.belongsToMany(models.GPhone, { through: 'b_clients_register', foreignKey: 'client_id' });
    this.belongsToMany(models.BClientRegister, { through: 'b_clients_register', foreignKey: 'client_id' });
  }
}
```

This is the model BClientRegister

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

export default class BClientRegister extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        client_id: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        },
        address_id: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        phones_id: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
      },
      {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'b_clients_register',
      },
    );
    return this;
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsToMany(models.GAddress, { through: 'b_clients_register', foreignKey: 'client_id' });
    this.belongsToMany(models.GPhone, { through: 'b_clients_register', foreignKey: 'client_id' });
    this.belongsToMany(models.BClientName, { through: 'b_clients_register', foreignKey: 'address_id' });
  }
}
```

This is the model GAddres

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

export default class GAddress extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        street: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
          defaultValue: '',
          validate: {
            notEmpty: {
              msg: 'Campo não pode ser vazio.',
            },
          },
        },
        number: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        neighborhood: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        zipcode: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        reference: {
          type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
      },
      {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'g_addresses',
      },
    );
    return this;
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsToMany(models.BClientName, { through: 'b_clients_register', foreignKey: 'address_id' });
    this.belongsToMany(models.GPhone, { through: 'b_clients_register', foreignKey: 'address_id' });
  }
}
```

This is the model GPhone:

```
import Sequelize, { Model } from 'sequelize';

export default class GPhone extends Model {
  static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
      {
        phone_number: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          defaultValue: '',
          validate: {
            notEmpty: {
              msg: 'Campo não pode ser vazio.',
            },
          },
        },
        cod_area: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        },
        cod_country: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        },
      },
      {
        sequelize,
        tableName: 'g_phones',
      },
    );
    return this;
  }

  static associate(models) {
    this.belongsToMany(models.BClientName, { through: 'b_clients_register', foreignKey: 'phones_id' });
    this.belongsToMany(models.GAddress, { through: 'b_clients_register', foreignKey: 'phones_id' });
  }
}
```